# Getting path from find command to variable

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

So this is my shell script so far, it's very simple
I just want the user to give a directory, then it'll find it and give back the permissions and name of the files in the directory.

```
echo '#!/bin/bash' > ex1
echo 'echo 'Which is the directory to list?'' >> ex1
echo 'read directory' >> ex1
echo 'path=`find / -type d -name $directory`' >> ex1
echo '$(find $path -printf '%M %P\n')' >> ex1
```

I've done that so far but when I run it, it gets me an error:

```
./ex1: line 5: drwxr-xr-x: command not recognized
```

(ex1 is the name of the shell script and it's inside the folder I'm using to test the shell script)

Comment: This is probably far simpler using a quoted here-document. `cat <<'EOF' > ex1` ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
echo '$(find $path -printf '%M %P\n')' >> ex1
```

Get rid of the `$(...)`. Just run the find command directly. You also should fix the inner single quotes, such as by switching them to double quotes.

```
echo 'find $path -printf "%M %P\n"' >> ex1
```